# How to set picture aspect ratio?

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sub ExampleUsage()
    Dim myPicture As String, myRange As Range
    myPicture = Application.GetOpenFilename _
        ("Pictures (*.gif; *.jpg; *.bmp; *.tif),*.gif; *.jpg; *.bmp; *.tif", _
        , "Select Picture to Import")

    Set myRange = Selection
    InsertAndSizePic myRange, myPicture
End Sub

Sub InsertAndSizePic(Target As Range, PicPath As String)
    Dim p As Object
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set p = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(PicPath)

    If Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then Set Target = Target.MergeArea
    With Target
        p.Top = .Top
        p.Left = .Left
        p.Width = .Width
        p.Height = .Height
    End With
End Sub
```

This is my code for Microsoft Excel. I want to have the aspect ratio unlock so that I can fill the entire merged cell. Thanks in advance.

Comment: FYI its not my code. . . i borrowed it. I dont want to take credit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you'll set the *Aspect Ratio*.
 It is a *Property* of the *Shape Object*. `p` is of `Picture Object Type`. You can use it's name to access it via `Shapes` which has the *Aspect Ratio* property:

```
Sub InsertAndSizePic(Target As Range, PicPath As String)
    Dim p As Object
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim sh As Worksheet: Set sh = ActiveSheet
    Set p = sh.Pictures.Insert(PicPath)
    sh.Shapes(p.Name).LockAspectRatio = False

    If Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then Set Target = Target.MergeArea
    With Target
        p.Top = .Top
        p.Left = .Left
        p.Width = .Width
        p.Height = .Height
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I declared and set variable for *Worksheet Object* just to have Intellisense kick in to get the arguments.

Another way is to use `Shape Object AddPicture Method` like below.

```
Sub InsertAndSizePic(Target As Range, PicPath As String)
    Dim s As Shape
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim sh As Worksheet: Set sh = ActiveSheet

    If Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then Set Target = Target.MergeArea
    With Target
        Set s = sh.Shapes.AddPicture(PicPath, True, True, .Left, .Top, .Width, .Height)
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

This code will also accomplish what the first code does. HTH.

Comment: Thanks for you help that worked perfect. I don't know or understand code. This makes my job a lot easier i work with excel every day.